# JPA mapping relations

Tags: database, jpa, entity-relationship, entity-model

Suppose I have 3 entities: *MonitorPeriod*, *Monitor* and *File*.

Now the requirement said that for each *MonitorPeriod*, which table is something like below:

```
ID, DATE_FROM, DATE_TO
1     <value>  <value>
```

I have One and just One *Monitor*, which table could be something like below:

```
ID, COMPILED,  ID_PERIOD, ID_FILE
1   true/false    1            1
```

Now, each *File*, which table could be something like below:

```
ID, NAME,    DESCRIPTION
1   <value>  <value>
```

could have N *Monitor* but Just one per *MonitorPeriod*.

Is there a way to achieve this with JPA Model? The Entity Model should create even the constraint that stop me to insert, inside monitor table, two tuplas with same *MonitorPeriod* ID and same *File* ID.

‐‐‐‐----‐-------------‐UPDATE --------------------

Yes Chris you are completely right! Is the same thing I have said to my functional analyst.

The goal is to design this three entity relationship in a way that, in the *Monitor* table:

```
ID, NAME, DESCRIPTION, ID_PERIOD, ID_FILE
```

I will have a constraint that permit me to insert, for example:

```
ID, NAME, DESCRIPTION, ID_PERIOD, ID_FILE
1   null       null       1           1        // ok
2   null       null       2           1        // ok
3   null       null       1           2        // ok
4   null       null       2           2        // should throw error because file 2 is already linked with monitor period 1
```

I try to repeat the logic: a *MonitorPeriod* (example from january to march) can have one and just one *Monitor* (suppose that monitor contains details on file, like size and extensions, thats it). And this is a `@OneToOne` relation. Now the problem is that a *File* can have more monitors but one for period and if a connect *File* with `@OneToMany` relationship with *Monitor* I can't achieve the situation above.

Maybe I should connect the entity differently or insert another table, I will try up and let you know. In the meanwhile if someone can suggest me some I will appreciate a lot!

Comment: it isn't clear from your description the relationships - What would your java object model look like? Start with that, then work on the JPA/DB schema, but it should be pretty straightforward if you look at JPA examples and demos out there with OneToOne, ManyToOne and OneToMany relationships - they all use constraints.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do this without adding useless tables or contort the ER logic.

As I said I have a *MonitorPeriod*:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "monitor_period")
@Data
public class MonitorPeriod {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private Integer id;

  private LocalDate dateFrom;
  private LocalDate dateTo;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "monitorPeriod")
  private List<Monitor> monitor;
}
```

Now I have my *File*:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "file")
@Data
public class File {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private Integer id;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "file")
  private List<Monitor> monitor;
}
```

As said before, *File* (in his life) can has more *Monitor* but just one per *MonitorPeriod*

So the *Monitor* table:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "monitor", uniqueConstraints = { 
    @UniqueConstraint(name = "UniquePeriodoAndMonitor", columnNames = { "id_period", "id_file" }) 
    }
)
@Data
public class Monitor {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private Integer id;

  private Boolean compilato;

  @ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name = "id_period")
  private MonitorPeriod monitorPeriod;

  @ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name = "id_file")
  private File file;
}
```

Hope helps..